# Dict keys not changing when loop iterates

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a program that goes through sales data and is supposed to sum the sales amounts by State and Quarter. I have a nested dict set up with the quarters inside each state key, like
`statesByQ = dict.fromkeys([set of state codes], [dict of quarters])`

Then I have a for loop that loops through a DataFrame, indexed by unique names in each row, and grab the state, quarter and amount from each. It then should add the amount to the specific nested dict point for each state and quarter as shown below

```
for opps in sdfs.index:
    amount = sdfs["Amount"][opps]
    state = sdfs['Billing State/Province'][opps]
    fisp =sdfs['Fiscal Period'][opps]
    statesByQ[state][fisp] += amount
```

But when I go through and look at the results, it just keeps summing all the amounts regardless of the place in the dict it was pointing at the given time and assigning those as the value. Here is what it looks like if I print out each variable:

```
opps: ALI: BOB,MO_Maker45_04.17-18.2019
state: MO
fisp: Q2-2019
amount: 19837.85
value assigned to dict: 19837.85
opps: ALI: JOHN, VA_L4_05.06.2019
state: VA
fisp: Q2-2019
amount: 10059.36
value assigned to dict: 29897.21
```

Edit: Adding sample data

[image: So each row is one sale, and I want to sum all the sales for each state by fiscal period.]

So to re-iterate, the issue is it doesn't seem to be properly passing the new keys for the dictionary even though their variable's value has changed i.e. Though the `state` and `fisp` variables have updated with the new keys from the Dataframe, they don't seem to being getting passed to the dictionary properly. If I go into debugging and watch the dictionary fill, it will take the first `amount` value and put it in it's proper place, then it will take the next amount value and add it to the previous even if they are not the same, then sets both dict locations to the same value. So in my example above, both `statesByQ['MO']['Q2-2019']` and `statesByQ['VA']['Q2-2019']` are set to 29897.21 instead of their respective 19837.85 and 10059.36

Comment: Show us an example of the DataFrame - enough to be able to reproduce the problem. - [mcve]

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers. This is a pretty important point to understand, so can you please give a simple example of the behavior you are seeing that is contrary to what you *expect?*

Comment: Sorry, terminology was never my strong suite. I edited and added an example of my data and a better explanation of what's going wrong.